# React testing setup with rails/webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've added [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) to my existing rails app, everything is working like a charm.

Webpack config is found under

```
config/webpack/shared.js
config/webpack/development.js
config/webpack/production.js
```

node_modules are installed in

```
vendor/node_modules
```

js pack files are in

```
app/javascript/packs/application.js
```

I've installed react and wrote a little component:

```
app/javascript/discover/example.jsx
```

Now I struggle with how to setup a working test environment. Normally I'd say the usual test setup should include: `karma`, `jasmine` or `mocha`, `webpack`.

Where should the config files live? Where will the test files be stored and to build a `karma.config.js` to bundle everything together.

It would be great to have a sample application that shows how to do all that correctly, but I obviously lack the necessary skills to plug everything together correctly.

This is not an easy to answer question, but having such an example application would be extremely helpful to a lot of people that'd want to use webpacker in the future.

Thanks for any thoughts on that topic,
Jo

**Some helpful resources:**

1. https://medium.com/@scbarrus/how-to-get-test-coverage-on-react-with-karma-babel-and-webpack-c9273d805063#.g6p5go9gd
2. http://qiita.com/kimagure/items/f2d8d53504e922fe3c5c
3. http://nicolasgallagher.com/how-to-test-react-components-karma-webpack/
4. https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/test-reactjs-components-karma-webpack

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NOTE:** The process I went through to answer this question is not longer necessary, as the Rails team has [moved JavaScript dependencies back into the root](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28093) of the project by default.

---

This answer is a two-parter. First, I'll explain how, after much blood, sweat and tears, I arrived at my current Webpacker + React + Jest test environment. Second, I'll dive into why all the expenditure of the bodily fluids.

## Part 1: Implementation

1. Rails. I generated a new Rails app, skipping all of the things that I'm not likely to need.

   ```
   rails new rails-react --skip-action-mailer --skip-active-record --skip-action-cable --skip-javascript --skip-turbolinks
   ```
2. Until Rails 5.1 ships, we need Webpacker.

   ```
   # Gemfile
   gem 'webpacker', git: 'https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git'
   ```

   Then in your shell

   ```
   $ bundle install
   ```
3. Set up Webpack and React using Webpacker

   ```
   $ rails webpacker:install && rails webpacker:install:react
   ```
4. Install Jest, and Jest related packages

   ```
   $ bin/yarn add jest babel-jest babel-polyfill react-test-renderer --dev
   ```
5. Configure Jest to play nice with Webpacker. [This article](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html) on configuring Jest for Webpack is very helpful. According to the docs "`<rootDir>` is a special token that gets replaced by Jest with the root of your project. Most of the time this will be the folder where your package.json is located". Crucially for us this is `/vendor` and not `/` as it would be in a conventional JavaScript project.

   ```js
   // vendor/package.json
   "jest": {
     // The name of this directive will soon change to "roots"
     // https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2600
     // This points Jest at Webpacker's default JS source directory
     "testPathDirs": [
       "<rootDir>/../app/javascript/packs"
     ],
     // This ensures that node_modules are resolved properly
     // By default, Jest looks in "/" for this, not "vendor/"
     "moduleDirectories": [
       "<rootDir>/node_modules"
     ],
     "moduleFileExtensions": [
       "js",
       "jsx"
     ]
   }
   ```
6. Babel. This one caused me the most headache. Babel doesn't support dynamic configuration (although it is [currently being considered](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/4892)). Additionally, the way Babel looks for configuration does not help us. "Babel will look for a .babelrc in the current directory of the file being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the directory tree until it finds either a .babelrc, or a package.json with a "babel": {} hash within."

   The way Babel looks for presets is also brittle. You'll note that [the babel-handbook documentation for creating presets](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/user-handbook.md#making-your-own-preset) include the step "simply publish this to npm and you can use it like you would any preset". If you want Babel to actually find a preset in the conventional way, there is no alternative to using an npm package inside of the `node_modules` directory with a name starting with `babel-preset`.

   This means that we need to create a `.babelrc` file in the Rails root, and then use the full path to each plugin that we need, relative to that `.babelrc` file, rather than the short-hand that you'll be familiar with if you've used Babel in the past (e.g. `"presets": ["react"]` refers to `node_modules/babel-preset-react`). My `.babelrc`, following the Jest docs on [using Webpack 2](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html#using-with-webpack-2) and [using babel](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#using-babel) looks like this:

   ```js
   // .babelrc
   {
     "presets": [
       "./vendor/node_modules/babel-preset-react",
       "./vendor/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015"
     ],
     "env": {
       "test": {
         "plugins": [
           "./vendor/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Remove the `options` key under the `babel-loader` configuration in `config/webpack/shared.js` so that Webpack uses this configuration file, too.

That brings us up to the present moment. I implemented the basic sum (vanilla JS) and [Link](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#snapshot-testing) (React) tests in the Jest docs and run them by executing `npm run test` in the `/vendor` directory. You can see the fruits of my labors here: https://github.com/pstjean/webpacker-jest

## Part 2. Why?

This is not an easy thing to do right now. It should be. The root of our problems is the unconventional directory structure imposed by Webpacker.

The original reasoning for moving all of our Yarn and Webpack files under `/vendor` is that, according to DHH, having these things in the project root as is convention is not "a beautiful way to cohabit app-focused JS within a Rails app". You can see the discussion on the commit implementing this [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27245). User [lemonmade's comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27245#issuecomment-264972185) on this commit foretells our current frustrations: "It will make actually configuring any JavaScript tooling extremely difficult, and causes it to behave differently than it would in any other project that uses npm packages."

Downthread, DHH says "Appreciate the input and will keep it under advisement as we go forward. This isn't set in stone, but for now we're going to try to make this work." In my opinion, this isn't tenable, and hopefully the Rails team will realize that before 5.1 launches with this in core. There is currently a [very promising pull request](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/84) to remedy this issue in the webpacker project. Let's hope it gets some traction!

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer and the work you've put into it. Our setup looks quite similar to yours now. Maybe a blog post to summarize the while setup would be a good idea..

Comment: I'm still holding out hope that the Rails team will add a configuration option to allow JavaScript dependencies in the root of a Rails project, and this information will be obsolete. If that doesn't end up happening, a blog post is definitely in order.

Comment: Looks like they've already made the decision to move everything to root: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/84#issuecomment-281351614

Comment: Here's a quick rundown on the simpler config with everything in root: https://medium.com/@kylefox/how-to-setup-javascript-testing-in-rails-5-1-with-webpacker-and-jest-ef7130a4c08e